# I want to test AspNetActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider functionality .Is it possible to test this in my local machine not network

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership

I have developed application in which users will create in active directory using registration.
This application will be use in Intranet but I want to test registration page in local machine
How to do this in my local machine.You can say I want to create test environment for active directory.

It is working fine when I set aspnetMembershipProvider as default
users are created successfully in database

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to have a look at [AD LDS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa705884%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). It'll allow you to setup a local light weight AD instance. There is a download for [windows 7](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=14683) available. I haven't tried this myself.